# Percentage/ratio difference when comparing different sizes specific terminology

Tags: ratio

Given 2 amounts:

101,000,000.00 and divide by 100,000,000.00 * 100 we get 101.00

Then if we take and subtract 50 million from both:

51,000,000.00 and divide by 50,000,000.00 * 100 we get 102.00

Is there a specific term to describe the difference going from 101.00 to 102.00 in the context of the above calculations? Even though the difference between the original numbers in both calculations is the exact same 1,000,000.00.

I understand why it happening. My question is what you call this effect when explaining to someone. Scale Change? Magnitude Change? Proportion Change? etc... When the 2 calculations jump by a large amount like 50,000,000.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide the original amount by two like you did here, but keep the change (increase) constant, then your percent increase will double. Here, it goes from $1\%%$ to $2\%%$.

This happens because, as a percentage, the amount of change is now twice what it was before.

Comment: I suppose as a generic phase I could say, "As a percentage, the amount of change is now considerably larger than it was before.", it's not usually exactly twice.

I was hoping there was some math term for this they could google something specific to understand it without having to walk them through it with examples. 

Close enough.